Gradient with respect to $LDL^\prime$ parameterization of covariance matrix
I have been working with the matrix-variate normal distribution (a.k.a., matrix normal distribution) $\mathbf{X} \sim \text{Normal}_{nm}\big(\mathbf{M},\;\mathbf{I}_n,\mathbf{V}\big)$, such that (ignoring constants):
$$ f(\mathbf{X}|\mathbf{M},\mathbf{V})=|\mathbf{I}_n|^{-m/2}|\mathbf{V}|^{-n/2}\exp\Big\lbrace-\dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\Big[\mathbf{I}_n\big(\mathbf{X}-\mathbf{M}\big)\mathbf{V}^{-1}\big(\mathbf{X}-\mathbf{M}\big)^{\prime}\Big]\Big\rbrace$$
where $\mathbf{M}$ is an $n\times m$ mean matrix, $\mathbf{I}_n$ is $n\times n$ the variance matrix among rows (identity matrix in this case), and $\mathbf{V}$ is the $m\times m$ covariance matrix among columns. I would like to get the gradient of the $\log$ of the above function, with respect to the $\mathbf{L}$ and $\mathbf{D}$ components of the $\mathbf{V}=\mathbf{L}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{L}^{\prime}$ parameterization of the covariance matrix. $\mathbf{L}$ is a lower-triangular matrix with ones along the diagonal, and $\mathbf{D}$ is a diagonal matrix with strictly positive entries. I would use the gradient in estimation procedures (e.g., gradient descent) but I'm not sure if what I have done so far is correct. Using the differential (Magnus and Neudecker), properties of the determinant (for lower triangular matrices), and defining $\mathbf{E}=\mathbf{X}-\mathbf{M}$, for $\mathbf{L}$ I have:
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathsf{d}(\log f) &=-\dfrac{n}{2}\mathsf{d}(\log|\mathbf{V}|)-\dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\Big[\mathsf{d}\big(\mathbf{E}^{\prime}\mathbf{E}\mathbf{V}^{-1}\big)\Big]\\
&=-\dfrac{n}{2}\mathsf{d}\big(\log|\mathbf{L}| +\log|\mathbf{D}|+\log|\mathbf{L}^{\prime}|\big) - \dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\Big[\mathbf{E}^{\prime}\mathbf{E}\mathsf{d}\big(\mathbf{V}^{-1}\big)\Big]\\
&=-\dfrac{n}{2}\mathsf{d}(\log|\mathbf{D}|)+\dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\Big[\mathbf{E}^{\prime}\mathbf{E}\mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathsf{d}(\mathbf{V})\mathbf{V}^{-1}\Big]\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\Big[\mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathbf{E}^{\prime}\mathbf{E}\mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathsf{d}\big(\mathbf{L}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{L}^{\prime}\big)\Big]\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\Big\lbrace\mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathbf{E}^{\prime}\mathbf{E}\mathbf{V}^{-1}\big[\mathsf{d}(\mathbf{L})\mathbf{D}\mathbf{L}^{\prime}+ \mathbf{L}\mathbf{D}\mathsf{d}(\mathbf{L}^{\prime})\big]\Big\rbrace\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{vec}\big(\mathbf{E}^{\prime}\mathbf{E}\big)^{\prime}\big(\mathbf{V}^{-1}\otimes\mathbf{V}^{-1}\big)\big[\big(\mathbf{LD}\otimes\mathbf{I}_m\big)\mathsf{d}\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{L})+\mathbb{K}_m\big(\mathbf{LD}\otimes\mathbf{I}_m\big)\mathsf{d}\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{L})\big]\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{vec}\big(\mathbf{E}^{\prime}\mathbf{E}\big)^{\prime}\big(\mathbf{V}^{-1}\otimes\mathbf{V}^{-1}\big)\big[\big(\mathbf{I}_m + \mathbb{K}_m\big)\big(\mathbf{LD}\otimes\mathbf{I}_m\big)\mathsf{d}\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{L})\big]\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{vec}\big(\mathbf{E}^{\prime}\mathbf{E}\big)^{\prime}\big(\mathbf{V}^{-1}\otimes\mathbf{V}^{-1}\big)\big[\big(\mathbf{I}_m + \mathbb{K}_m\big)\big(\mathbf{LD}\otimes\mathbf{I}_m\big)\mathbb{D}_m\mathsf{d}\mathrm{vech}(\mathbf{L})\big]\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{vec}\big(\mathbf{E}^{\prime}\mathbf{E}\big)^{\prime}\big(\mathbf{V}^{-1}\otimes\mathbf{V}^{-1}\big)\big[\big(\mathbf{I}_m + \mathbb{K}_m\big)\big(\mathbf{LD}\otimes\mathbf{I}_m\big)\mathbb{D}_m\big]
\end{align*}
$$
where $\mathbb{K}_m$ is an $m^2\times m^2$ commutation matrix, and $\mathbb{D}_m$ is an $m^2\times m(m+1)/2$ duplication matrix. From here, I'd still have to extract the strictly lower-triangular elements of $\mathbf{L}$ since the ones along the diagonal are not needed. Now, with respect to $\mathbf{D}$,  and because I'm interested in $\mathbf{D}$ having positive entries, define $B_{ii}=\log\big(D_{ii}\big)$ such that $D_{ii}=\exp\big(B_{ii}\big)$ and
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathsf{d}(\log f) &=-\dfrac{n}{2}\mathsf{d}(\log|\mathbf{V}|)-\dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\Big[\mathsf{d}\big(\mathbf{E}^{\prime}\mathbf{E}\mathbf{V}^{-1}\big)\Big]\\
&= -\dfrac{n}{2}\mathsf{d}\log(|\mathbf{D}|) - \dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\Big[\mathbf{E}^{\prime}\mathbf{E}\mathsf{d}\big(\mathbf{V}^{-1}\big)\Big]\\
&=-\dfrac{n}{2}\mathrm{tr}\big[\mathbf{D}^{-1}\mathsf{d}\big(\mathbf{D}\big)\big] + \dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\Big[\mathbf{E}^{\prime}\mathbf{E}\mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathsf{d}\big(\mathbf{L}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{L}^{\prime}\big)\mathbf{V}^{-1}\Big]\\
&=-\dfrac{n}{2}\mathrm{tr}\big[\mathbf{D}^{-1}\mathrm{diag}(\exp(\mathbf{b}))\mathsf{d}\mathbf{b}\big] + \dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\Big[\mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathbf{E}^{\prime}\mathbf{E}\mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathbf{L}\mathsf{d}(\mathbf{D})\mathbf{L}^{\prime}\Big]\\
&=-\dfrac{n}{2}\mathrm{tr}\big(\mathbf{I}_m\mathsf{d}\mathbf{b}\big) + \dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\Big[\mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathbf{E}^{\prime}\mathbf{E}\mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathbf{L}\mathrm{diag}(\exp(\mathbf{b}))\mathsf{d}(\mathbf{b})\mathbf{L}^{\prime}\Big]\\
&=-\dfrac{n}{2}\mathrm{tr}\big(\mathbf{I}_m\mathsf{d}\mathbf{b}\big) + \dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}\Big[\mathbf{L}^{\prime}\mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathbf{E}^{\prime}\mathbf{E}\mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathbf{L}\mathbf{D}\mathsf{d}(\mathbf{b})\Big]\\
&= -\dfrac{n}{2}\mathrm{diag}^{-1}\big(\mathbf{I}_m\big) + \dfrac{1}{2}\mathrm{diag}^{-1}\Big(\mathbf{L}^{\prime}\mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathbf{E}^{\prime}\mathbf{E}\mathbf{V}^{-1}\mathbf{L}\mathbf{D}\Big)
\end{align*}
$$
where $\mathrm{diag}^{-1}(\cdot)$ extracts the diagonal elements of the input (square) matrix, and $\mathbf{b}=[b_{1},\dots,b_{m}]$. As I mentioned above, I am not entirely sure if both gradients are correct but I'd very much appreciate any insights/input.

$
\def\k{\otimes}  \def\h{\tfrac12}  \def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\bR#1{\big(#1\big)}
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\vh#1{\op{vech}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\g#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\ggrad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\g{\p #2}}}
\def\V{V^{-1}}
$Let's reserve $(D,E)$ for the Duplication and Elimination matrices and rename $\,F=\LR{X-M}\,$
and $\,P=\Diag p\,$ for the factorization, i.e. $\,V=LPL^T$
First calculate the differential of the function with respect to $V$
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \log(f) = -\h\trace{F^TF\V} \;-\; \tfrac n2\,\log(\det(V)) \\
\\
d\phi &= -\tfrac 12\LR{F^TF:d\V} \;-\; \tfrac n2\, d\trace{\log(V)} \\
 &= \h\LR{\V F^TF\V}:{dV} \;-\; \h\, n\V:{dV} \\
 &= \h\BR{\V F^TF\V-n\V}:{dV} \\
 &\equiv \h A:\g{dV} \\
}$$
Then substitute your preferred factorization
$\big($and also $\,\ell=\vh L,\;\;p=\exp(b),\;\;dp=P\,db\,\big)$
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= \h A:\LR{\c{dL}\:PL^T + LP\:\c{dL^T} + L\:\c{dP}\:L^T} \\
 &= \h ALP^T:dL \;+\; \h P^TL^TA:dL^T \;+\; \h L^TAL:dP \\
 &= ALP:dL \;+\; \h L^TAL:\Diag{dp} \\
 &= \vc{ALP}:\vc{dL} \;+\; \h\,\diag{L^TAL}:\g{dp} \\
 &= \vc{ALP}:E^T\vh{dL} \;+\; \h\,\diag{L^TAL}:P\,db \\
 &= E\vc{ALP}:\vh{dL} \;+\; \h\,P\diag{L^TAL}:db \\
 &= \vh{ALP}:\g{d\ell} \;+\; \h\,P\diag{L^TAL}:\g{db} \\
}$$
Finally, pick out any desired gradients
$$\eqalign{
\ggrad{\phi}V &= \h A
,\qquad&\ggrad{\phi}{p} = \h\,\diag{L^TAL} \\
\ggrad{\phi}{\ell} &= \vh{ALP}
,\qquad&\ggrad{\phi}b = \h P\diag{L^TAL}
\\\\
}$$

Here is a description of the notations used in the above derivation.
The diag() function extracts the diagonal from its matrix argument and returns it as a column vector, while Diag() creates a diagonal matrix from its vector argument.
A colon denotes the indispensable Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
B:B &= \frob{B}^2  \\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{XY}:B &= X:\LR{BY^T} \;=\; Y:\LR{X^TB} \\
G = \grad{\phi}X &\qif d\phi=G:dX \\
}$$
The Elimination and Duplication matrices act as usual when applied to a symmetric matrix
$$\eqalign{
\vh V = E\,\vc V, \qquad \vc V = D\,\vh V \ne E^T\vh V \\
}$$
but exhibit surprising behavior when applied to a lower triangular matrix
$$\eqalign{
\vh L &= E\,\vc L, \qquad \vc L = E^T\vh L \ne D\,\vh L \\
\vh L &= D^T\vc L
}$$
When applied to a non-symmetric, non-triangular matrix like
$X=ALP,\;$ the vech() function can be defined as
$$\eqalign{
\vh X \:\equiv\, E\,\vc X, \quad\;\; \vc X =\; ??
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad
}$$
but this function is irreversible, i.e. there's no way to recover $\vc X\,!!\;$ This corresponds to the fact that $DE\ne I\:$ whereas
$\,ED,\,D^TE^T,\,{\rm and}\,EE^T$ are all equal to $I$.

Thank you for the detailed explanation @greg. This is very useful.

@Greg, I have the feeling that the expression $\mathbf{ALP}:d\mathbf{L}$ is wrong since  $\mathbf{L}$ is lower-triangular but I cannot figure what to do with this information ?

It wasn't clear why you chose the $LDL^T$ factorization. I would have used $V=YY^T,$ where $Y$ is an unconstrained matrix. Then the gradient of $\phi$ wrt to $Y$ is $,G=AY,$ and this can easily be incorporated into gradient descent algorithms, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
Y_0 &= random \
Y_{k+\tt1} &= Y_{k} - \lambda_k A_kY_k \
k &= k+{\tt1} \
}$$

I initially thought that $V = \mathbf{LDL}^{\prime}$ would be better to "guarantee" that the resulting covariance matrix was positive definite.
